# How to fix columns that collide with each other after sidebar is active?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

**good**

[image]

**bad**

[image]

In the first picture called 'good' we can see that the card `divs` don't collide at each other, but in the second picture when sidebar is active they collide.

I've tried to change from `col-md-6` to `col-md-12` on that,
but then the site looks not that as I wish when sidebar is closed.

I think when sidebar is active it supposed to change from `col-md-6` to `col-md-12`, but I have no clue how to do that.

I'm a begginer so I will a appreciate some suggestions to fix that problem :)

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}

p {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
#zegar {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.card {
  width: 20rem;
}
#chartbtn {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
.card-text {
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.navbar {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
  perspective: 1500px;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  background: #3e5e82;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.945, 0.02, 0.27, 0.665);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: -250px;
  transform: rotateY(100deg);
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #3a5678;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #3a5678;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active > a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #3a5678;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #3e5e82;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #3a5678;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */
#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebarCollapse {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#sidebarCollapse span {
  width: 80%;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background: #555;
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.81, -0.33, 0.345, 1.375);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

#sidebarCollapse span:first-of-type {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
}
#sidebarCollapse span:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
#sidebarCollapse span:last-of-type {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
}

#sidebarCollapse.active span {
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
  #sidebar.active {
    margin-left: 0;
    transform: none;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse span:first-of-type,
  #sidebarCollapse span:nth-of-type(2),
  #sidebarCollapse span:last-of-type {
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 5px auto;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse.active span {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse.active span:first-of-type {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
  }
  #sidebarCollapse.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #sidebarCollapse.active span:last-of-type {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
  }
}
```

```html
<?Php
require_once "connect.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM chartjs";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    //loop through the returned data (jakies randomowe znaczki zeby chartjs umial dane wczytac)
    $temperature = $row['temp2'];
    $humidity = $row['hum'];
    $day = $row['day'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Uber duper</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/zegar.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="js/timeago.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script>
        var date = <?php echo json_encode($day, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Stacja Pogodowa</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p></p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" aria-expanded="false">Panel głowny</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Wykresy</a>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Czujniki</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">DHT22</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">DS18B20</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">BMP180</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>


        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content Holder -->
        <div id="content">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </button>

                    <body onload="odliczanie();">
                        <div id="zegar"></div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- początek głownego containera-->
            <div class="container float-left">
                <!-- początek rowa-->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- początek cola-->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 pt-4">
                        <!-- początek carda-->
                        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <h4 class="d-inline-block pt-2 pl-1">DHT22 </h4>
                                        <h3>
                                            <div class="pr-1 pl-1 d-inline-block">
                                                <i class=" fas fa-thermometer-three-quarters"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                            echo $temperature;
                                            ?>&deg;C
                                        </h3>
                                        <h3>
                                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                                                <i class="fas fa-tint"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                            echo $humidity;
                                            ?>%
                                        </h3>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">


                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-2" id="chartbtn"><i class="fas fa-chart-line" style="font-size:24px"></i></button>


                                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted" id="timeago">

                                                <script>
                                                    document.getElementById("timeago").innerHTML = time_ago(date);
                                                </script>

                                            </small></p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- koniec carda-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- koniec cola-->
                    <div class="col-md-6  col-xl-4 pt-4">
                        <!-- początek carda-->
                        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <h4 class="d-inline-block pt-2 pl-1">DHT22 </h4>
                                        <h3>
                                            <div class="pr-1 pl-1 d-inline-block">
                                                <i class=" fas fa-thermometer-three-quarters"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                            echo $temperature;
                                            ?>&deg;C
                                        </h3>
                                        <h3>
                                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                                                <i class="fas fa-tint"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                            echo $humidity;
                                            ?>%
                                        </h3>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">


                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-2" id="chartbtn"><i class="fas fa-chart-line" style="font-size:24px"></i></button>


                                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted" id="timeago">

                                                <script>
                                                    document.getElementById("timeago").innerHTML = time_ago(date);
                                                </script>

                                            </small></p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- koniec carda-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- koniec cola-->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 pt-4">
                        <!-- początek carda-->
                        <div class="card d-inline-block ">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <h4 class="d-inline-block pt-2 pl-1">DHT22 </h4>
                                        <h3>
                                            <div class="pr-1 pl-1 d-inline-block">
                                                <i class=" fas fa-thermometer-three-quarters"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                            echo $temperature;
                                            ?>&deg;C
                                        </h3>
                                        <h3>
                                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                                                <i class="fas fa-tint"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                            echo $humidity;
                                            ?>%
                                        </h3>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">


                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-2" id="chartbtn"><i class="fas fa-chart-line" style="font-size:24px"></i></button>


                                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted" id="timeago">

                                                <script>
                                                    document.getElementById("timeago").innerHTML = time_ago(date);
                                                </script>

                                            </small></p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- koniec carda-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- koniec cola-->
                </div>
                <!-- koniec rowa-->
                <div class="row ">
                    <!-- początek cola-->
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 pt-4 ">
                        <!-- początek carda-->
                        <div class="card d-inline-block">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <h4 class="d-inline-block pt-2 pl-1">DHT22 </h4>
                                        <h3>
                                            <div class="pr-1 pl-1 d-inline-block">
                                                <i class=" fas fa-thermometer-three-quarters"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                            echo $temperature;
                                            ?>&deg;C
                                        </h3>
                                        <h3>
                                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                                                <i class="fas fa-tint"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                            echo $humidity;
                                            ?>%
                                        </h3>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">


                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-2" id="chartbtn"><i class="fas fa-chart-line" style="font-size:24px"></i></button>


                                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted" id="timeago">

                                                <script>
                                                    document.getElementById("timeago").innerHTML = time_ago(date);
                                                </script>

                                            </small></p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- koniec carda-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- koniec cola-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- koniec głownego containera-->
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
                $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `max-width: 20rem;` under your `.card` class as opposed to defining `width` itself. In this way the bootstrap column can help define the width when the available horizontal space in the row changes.

Answer (score 0):

They overlap because `.card` has `width: 20rem;` which related to [body's `font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#rem) and the container `.col-md-6` has `max-width: 50%` which related to parent container.

You can fix this by using `width: 50%` instead of `max-width: 50%` for `.col-md-6`, but be careful. You need to rewrite this class only for this case since you are using a fixed width for `.card` and don't rely on bootstrap's responsiveness.